# Search for a string in a txt file under multiple folders

Tags: batch-file, search

To put simply I am a temp IT for (Blank) motor company. I am trying to build a batch file that will search Progresslog.txt for a string. this string will be a user name like awilson. Thing is there is 1 progresslog.txt for each computer I have backed up under the folder names HMC(insert s/n) I need to search each progresslog for the string but can't figure out what I'm doing. This is what I have so far.

```
for /d /r ".\" %%a in (*) do if /i "%%~nxa"=="progresslog.txt" set "folderpath=%%a" & echo "%folderpath%"
for /f %%f in ('dir /b %folderpath%') do echo %%f & findstr /m "%Input%" progresslog.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
  echo Found String!
) else goto A
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a lot easier

```
findstr /s /l /m /c:"awilson" progresslog.txt
```

Just search in subdirectories (`/s`) the literal indicated (`/l /c:"..."`) in files named `progresslog.txt` and output only the name of files found (`/m`)

Comment: The `/C:"string"` option defaults to a literal serach, so the `/L` option is redunant.

Comment: The solution should work well for this case. But you have to be careful with the `/S` option. FINDSTR has a serious bug that can lead to skipped files under certain circumstances. See the section titled **BUG - Short 8.3 filenames can break the /D and /S options** at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8844873/1012053.

Comment: @dbenham, thank you. I have lost the count of how many times I have readed your answer on `findstr`. Yes I'm aware of the redundant switch (`findstr` has so many quirks that I prefer to precisely indicate what I'm doing) and of course all the bugs you documented. I think that in this case, with a fixed long file name, without wildcards, it should work.

Comment: Agreed - it should work here. I just wanted the OP to be aware that there are unexpected limitations to the `/S` option that could arise in seemingly similar use cases.